# Arithmetic Operations on Hash Values

Tags: algorithm, hash

Are there any hashing algorithms that are closed over arithmetic operations? More specifically, if `a` and `b` are two integers, is there any hashing algorithm `hash` that satisfies: `hash(a + b) == hash(a) + hash(b)` (and similarly for `-`, `*`, `/`)? Is it possible to modify these operators somehow to achieve this condition?

Comment: Other than `hash(x) => return x;`, I don't think so. How would that be useful?

Comment: `hash(x) => return 1;` Lot of collisions though :)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError That would lead to collisions, won't it?

Comment: Your question implies that you're trying to do something unusual. Care to tell us what problem you're trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose `h(a+b) = h(a) + h(b)`. Using induction you can show that `h(c * a)`, if `c` is a constant, is equal to `h(c*a) = c * h(a)`. Therefore, it means the function `h` must be linear (by the definition of the linear map in linear algebra), and every linear function such as `h(x) = c * x` (c is an integer and constant) could be the answer of your question. However, it is linear and would not be a helpful hash function! Moreover, you can do the same for the `-`.

For multiplication, it could be more complex. `h(a*b) = h(a)*h(b)`. You can get from this equation that for each constant `m` we can have `h(a^m) = h(a)^m`. Now, as you now, we can write each number with its factor likes `x = p_1^a_1 * p_2^a_2 * ... * p_k^a_k` that all of `p_i` is a prime number. Hence, `h(x) = h(p_1)^a_1 * h(p_2)^a_2 * ... * h(p_k)^a_k`. So, the value of `h` on the prime numbers is important and the other values will be determined by those values.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to modify these operators somehow to achieve this condition?

Yes: undo the hash. So for any operator a•b, calculate hash(hash⁻¹(a)•hash⁻¹(b)).

This works for any bijective hash, typical integer hashes fall into that category: compositions of multiply-by-odd-constant, bitwise rotation, XOR by constant, ADD constant, certain XOR/shifts. For example the Murmurhash finalizer.

For some combinations of hash and operator it's easier, for example a multiplicative hash is linear so it already distributes over addition and subtraction.